# Creating Java test rules

Tags: java, automated-tests

I will start to create a Java project from eclipse which will contain all Java tests to control GUI.

When I create project  I have :

```
TestProject\
             .\src
             .\Jre system library
```

Are there configuration rules?

Could I put all Java files in the same package under `src` and run configuration for each Java test?

Are there rules, documentation to help user to configure and create Java projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`JUnit`](http://www.junit.org/), you may find some guidance in the FAQ [*Organizing Tests*](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize).

Addendum: Using your Eclipse `Help > Help Contents` menu, search for "JUnit" to see details of how to set up test. As an example, here's a [link](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-junit.htm) to an older version.

Comment: thanks for the link it is useful but I do not found section explaining how to configure java project hw to run configuration ? what should we add from run->run config menu (from eclipse)?

Comment: my project will contain only junit tests ,which naming rules,configuration rules for each java project in eclipse)

Comment: The best guide is to search your version's `Help` system; I've added an example link above.